# Getting a 502 Bad Gateway error on live site after digitalocean one click django install

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, droplet

**Summary of problem**

- Getting a “**502 Bad Gateway** - nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)” error when visiting my live site.
- Only able to access site through a development server port:
  python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
- I can then access my site via www.myproject.com:8080 and everything works as it should
- I believe it has to do with gunicorn's inability to serve my project

**Technologies**

- python3
- django version 2.1.2
- Digitalocean

**Workflow up to the point of error**

- Created a droplet on digital ocean - following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-CT_l1dnVU&t=958s
- It seems many people in the comment section of that guide are experiencing the same issue
- Used digital ocean’s one click install for django
- Before uploading my project files I checked the live site to see that everything was in order, it was.
- Uploaded my project files and upgraded django
- Checked live site again, got the ‘502 Bad Gateway’ error
  [image: The 502 error]
- Tried switching back to the old version of django, that wasn’t the issue
- Followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04 and found that my gunicorn daemon is failing to start
- `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`
  [image: gunicorn.service]
- checked status of gunicorn `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`
  [image: failed to start]
- Checked error logs: `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn`
  [image: The error logs]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Project Files**
[image: directory]

Comment: Hello!! Have you added your domain (e.g www.myproject.com) to `ALLOWED_HOST` variable at `settings.py` file?

Comment: Yes @JônatasCastro

Comment: It seems gunicorn/Django is not starting properly. So `nginx` is returning 502. Things you should try:
1 - Force DEBUG=True at `settings.py`  
2 - Try to run the code after `ExecStart=` at from `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file  
3 - See if the directories of this command are correct  
4 - Check the errors from the command above

Comment: What is in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` ?

Comment: Also dont link to external sites, please.